# Automatic scroll is not working while drag and drop the rows when using oj-table with row reordering

Tags: oracle-jet

I am using oj-table with row reordering option. But when I try to drag and drop the rows the automatic scroll is not working. Suppose I have 50 rows in my table and want to drag the 50th row to 2nd row then automatic scroll is not working